# ScrollviewDidScroll not called at each point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

There is a button at the bottom of my view controller. When the user scrolls down the button has to be attached to the scrollview at certain height.

I need to attach a button to the scrollview, immediately when the `contentOffset.y` reaches a particular value. `-(void) scrollviewDidScroll` doesn't help me as there might be a jump in `contentOffset` when the user is scrolling fast. Any leads on this are helpful.

Also, whenever I add a subview to the scrollview, `-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called. Which in turn sets the contentOffset to `{0,0}`. How can I achieve the functionality I need?

Comment: Why do you put the button into the scroll view? If I understand your question right, the button should stick to the bottom of your view. So why not just add the button as a separate view below your scroll view?

Comment: Its not always at the bottom of the scrollview. Its initially at the bottom of my viewController's view. There is a scrollview as subview to this main view with same frame. I need my button to start scrolling along with the scrollview after certain content offset. Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: question is not clear. Are you need to add a button at the bottom of the scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do the same thing with a UITableView and for me using `scrollViewDidScroll` worked.

I created a view called staticBar and added it as a subview of the tableView, but I had to rearrange the tableview subviews for it to appear in the right place. I don't have my code in front of me, but in `-scrollViewDidScroll:` it looked something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    CGFloat staticBarAdjustedY = _staticBarY - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat scrollViewYFloor = scrollView.frame.size.height - _staticBar.frame.size.height;
    // This way maximum Y the view can have is at the base of the scrollView
    CGFloat newY = MIN( staticBarAdjustedY, scrollViewYFloor);
    _staticBar.frame = (CGRect){ { _staticBar.frame.origin.x, newY}, _staticBar.frame.size}
}
```

I will check my code later today and add more details here.

Also, you said the scrollviewDidScroll has jumps in contentOffset, but it's worth mentioning that these jumps are the same that the scrollView uses to scroll its own view. So it's not like you are "losing" frames on this delegate method.

Hope it helps.

PS: So, here is the rest of my code.

```
//I place my custom view as a subview of the tableView below it's last subview
//The last subview is for scroll indicators.
WTButtonsBar *buttonBar = [[WTButtonsBar alloc] init];
[self.tableView insertSubview:buttonBar belowSubview:self.tableView.subviews.lastObject];
```

In `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //In my app I needed my view to stick to the top of the screen
    //thats why I use MAX here
    //self.buttonsBarOriginalY is the view's position in the scrollView when it isn't attached to the top.
    CGFloat newY = MAX(scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.buttonsBarOriginalY)
    [_buttonsBar setFrame:(CGRect){{0, newY}, _buttonsBar.frame.size}];
}
```